# Handle server context in a Thymeleaf application running in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application with Thymeleaf on the front end side. I need to deploy the application to a Kubernetes cluster where it will be accessible on a path like this `my-k8s-cluster.com/my-application`.

The context path `/my-application` is configured on the Kubernetes side and is not a subject of the application to know about. It can be changed independently without changing the application code.

**Problem:** Independently from whether I use [context-relative URLs or server-relative URLs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)
Thymeleaf reffers to the server root. While the application is running on `my-k8s-cluster.com/my-application` Thymeleaf looks for its resources in `my-k8s-cluster.com/` and fails to load them.

**Question:** How to configure Thymeleaf to run independently with different context roots?

**Update:**
Here is how my Ingress configuration looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-k8s-cluster.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-application/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-service
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Are you using ingress? Please post the spec file.

Comment: @KoopaKiller please check the updated question.

Comment: can you share your code base by specifying how are you running ?

Comment: Sorry to reply this way, but you deleted your recent TeX question.as off-topic. I hope that means you solved it. If not: the installation of one of the dependencies, for some reason, was trying to set your timezone. You could run `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` first to make sure that's set. I don’t get that bug when I insall with `apt install texlive-full`.

Comment: Thank you @Davislor. Yes, the question was marked as an off topic that's why I removed it. As you said, the issue is related to timezone not being set (because it iwas inside Docker). I solved the issue by setting a `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` env variable before running the script

Comment: @Davislor thanks for you time once again. I obviously can't vote up an answer on a non-exisitng question that's why I voted up a couple of your answers here :) Have a nice day!

Comment: @SashaShpota I appreciate the thought, but [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) might get you in trouble. The accepted way to do what you want within the rules is to award a bounty. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, the next solution may be useful in your case.

According to [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#server-properties), `context-path` can be changed via property files.

By default `context-path` is `\`, but using the next setting `server.servlet.context-path` in the file with application properties it can be changed.

For example, in order to using `/my-application` as context-path, the next property `server.servlet.context-path=/my-application` should be added into  `application.properties`.

Also in [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config) are several approaches to changing this property:

As an example, it can be done via `OS environment variables` or `command-line arguments` and etc.

Thus, it is possible to set up this property via defining environment variables for a container in Kubernetes. More information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/)

Also, Spring Cloud supports reading properties from Kubernetes ConfigMap.
[Spring Cloud Kubernetes](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#configmap-propertysource) describe this case

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my-k8s-cluster.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-application/(.+)
            backend:
              serviceName: my-service
              servicePort: 80
```